Lexar NM790 4TB SSD keeps crashing my fresh install of Ubuntu 24.04
Lexar NM790 4TB SSD keeps crashing my fresh install of Ubuntu 24.04
I recently upgraded my SSD on my laptop.  The SSD is a 4TB Lexar NM790.  I used a similar 2 TB drive in another Lenovo laptop without issue.
Dell XPS 15 7590 Manufacturer firmware is fully patched.  I am unaware of any firmware updates for the SSD.
$ sudo dmidecode -s bios-version
1.28.0

$ sudo udisksctl status
MODEL                     REVISION  SERIAL               DEVICE
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
Lexar SSD NM790 4TB       12237     XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX   nvme0n1 

$ sudo nvme list
Node                  Generic               SN                   Model                                    Namespace  Usage                      Format           FW Rev  
--------------------- --------------------- -------------------- ---------------------------------------- ---------- -------------------------- ---------------- --------
/dev/nvme0n1          /dev/ng0n1            XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX   Lexar SSD NM790 4TB                      0x1          4.10  TB /   4.10  TB    512   B +  0 B   12237


Have you updated UEFI firmware & SSD fimware? Even new system may have update available. sudo dmidecode -s bios-version &
udisksctl status Compare to vendors support page for your model. I also like to install nvme-cli. Also shows firmware version: sudo nvme list

@oldfred - Yes, firmware is fully up to date. Both Dell laptop and Lexar SSD.

The solution was to add:
nvme_core.default_ps_max_latency_us=0 to boot line for the kernel.
That is in /etc/default/grub file the line GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT should look something like:
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash nvme_core.default_ps_max_latency_us=0"

Then after updating /etc/default/grub, run the following command:
sudo update-grub


The /proc/cmdline is:
BOOT_IMAGE=/boot/vmlinuz-6.8.6-060806-generic root=UUID=3abde92a-afef-478c-a16d-ff136ce7ab9e ro nvme_core.default_ps_max_latency_us=0

To get your computer to boot, you might need to edit grub when it first boots by adding nvme_core.default_ps_max_latency_us=0 after ro
Update Dec 2024
There is an updated firmware from Lexar.  In Windows, download and install Lexar DiskMaster.  Click in to Firmware upgrade.  DiskMaster reports my firmware at version 12237 and that 16949 is available.  I will update and report back.
I have now updated to firmware version, but DiskMaster did not work in Windows 11. I had to create a Windows 10 To Go USB disk.  I used the free version of WinToUSB.
I am now testing the Lexar 4TB NVMe drive without the nvme_core.default_ps_max_latency_us=0 grub bootloader option.
(Updates to be added)
